# Ending Interactivity Upon Declaring A Winner For an Online Game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a very simple JavaScript tic-tac-toe game which appears to be running well currently. It consists of an array which holds X's and O's, will not allow the same spot selection twice, and the computer turn is based off a random number generated which is still open in the array.

My only issues left are what to do when a winner is declared (computer or human).

At that point, I will need to end the JavaScript running the game until the user chooses to reset the board and start again.

This entails two details that I am struggling with:

1. I need the sectors of the tic-tac-toe board to become "unclickable" or to not register anymore clicks once the winner is declared. Currently even after a game is decided to be won or lost, if there are empty spaces left over then the user can continue to mark those spaces on the board.
2. Solving the above should help in part to solve this problem, but it might also be nice to completely stop the game overall once the game's winner is declared. Currently, again because the user can continue clicking open spaces if they exist, the counter (which counts wins for the user) will continue to increment as long as there exists a win on the board. Again though, by solving problem 1, transitively solve this problem as well since the clicks don't work and thereby the counter will not be incremented.

Comment: A simple thought would be to add a flag indicating the game has ended. Then in the click event handler of spaces in the board, check if the end game flag is true -> stop processing; false -> mark the space.

Comment: @TactMayers this seems very simple. I am new to javascript and cannot find an example online for the stop processing part of your statement with the event handler. Could you possibly provide a short code example? And by the way I am utilizing jquery for the click handler, but I will figure it out if you only know how to do it in regular javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ending the game is simply a matter of making the squares not respond to clicks, then you could just create a function that binds to the click event for the boxes.

For example, if each box is an link with a class of "box", then you could do:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(var key in boxes) { 
  boxes[key].onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or, using jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", ".boxes", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

You would do that after the winner is found:

```
var endGame = function() {
   $(document).on("click", ".boxes", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}

if ( there is a winner ) {
    endGame();
}
```

Comment: I like your approach. However, my concern is that once I use my reset button, which simply resets the board (all spaces blank) and the array back to blanks as well, how would I update the javascript yet again to tell the game it should be all clickable again? hopefully you understand what I'm saying

Comment: If you're using jQuery you can do $(document).off("click", ".boxes") to set the boxes back to normal.  That could be executed when the reset button is pressed.